# Save object with associations in Sequelizejs

Tags: sequelize.js

As far as I can tell, using Sequelizejs, there does not seem to be a way to  save object associations when the object itself is saved.

For example, I have a contact which can have 1 or more phoneNumber. Currently I have something like this for the association:

```
global.db.Contact.hasMany(global.db.PhoneNumber, {as: 'phoneNumbers'});
```

Using a rest endpoint I would like to post a new contact object (with any provided phone numbers) and save it to the database. My request object looks something like this:

```
{
    firstName: "john",
    lastName: "Doe",
    phoneNumbers: [
        { number: "555-555-5555", type: "home" }
    ]
}
```

Right now I pass this object to build:

```
var contact = Contact.build(req.body);
```

And then call save (I know I could use create instead of build/save but we have custom logic in the save to track the modified data and which user did the modification)

```
contact.save();
```

This throws the following error which kind of makes sense.

```
column "phoneNumbers" of relation "Contacts" does not exist
```

The sql call is trying to set the value of a column "phoneNumbers" which does not exist. I obviously don't want it to do that... I really would like it to bulk create each phoneNumber in the array with the ID of the contact I am creating.

The only example I found was this: https://gist.github.com/sdepold/3040391 and I don't really want to have to do this... Since I coming from a rest endpoint, I would like a way to do this operation generically (I'll have many models with associations). I will also need to be able to do these operations in bulk (for importing contacts from other sources) so I would prefer that it be the minimal amount of sql calls. Has anyone found a good way to do this?

Comment: I have the exact same question. Did you find any answer for this ?
I'm still on sequelize 1.7.

Comment: I never did find an elegant solution. I have since moved onto other projects that do not use Sequelize.

Answer (score 1):

Sequelize v4 introduced a new feature which allows creation of an instance along with any associated instances.

In your case, it allows adding multiple phone number against a single user as provided below.

```
return Contact.create({
  firstName: 'John',
  lastName: 'Doe',
  PhoneNumbers: [
    {
      number: '555-555-5555',
      type: 'home'
    },
    {
      number: '555-555-7777',
      type: 'work'
    }
  ]  
}, {
  include: [{
    association: Contact.PhoneNumber
  }]
});
```

Detailed documentation can be found here [Sequelize Docs - Creating with associations](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/associations.html#belongsto---hasmany---hasone-association)

Comment: What is "Product" here?

Comment: @JoshuaFoxworth, thanks for pointing out. It should be `Contact` instead of `Product`. I just updated the example now.

Answer (score 0):

I use this code

```
var createUser = function(req, reply) {
    db.User.create(req.payload).success(function(user) {
        saveGroups(req, reply, user);
    }).error(function(err) {
        console.error('Error occured', err);
        reply('Error');
    });
};

var saveGroups = function(req, reply, user) {
    db.UserGroup.destroy("user_id=" + user.id).success(function() {
        var groups = req.payload.userGroups;
        if (groups && groups.length > 0) {
            for (var i = 0; i < groups.length; i++) {
                groups[i].user_id = user.id;
            }
            db.UserGroup.bulkCreate(groups).success(function() {
                reply(user);
            }).error(function(err) {
                console.error('Error occured', err);
                reply('Error');
            });
        } else {
            reply(user);
        }
    }).error(function(err) {
        console.error('Error occured', err);
        reply('Error');
    });
};
```

- User is a model that hasMany UserGroup
- req.payload comes a JSON
- the destroy(...) is there to empty first the associations (in case we do an update)